# Move third party library file from armaebi-v7a folder to armaebi built folder

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, arm, crashlytics

Recently I have upgraded firebase crashlytics SDK to version 17.2.1 (NDK-version). This provide third party library **libcrashlytics.so** for artitecture **armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a** for arm based 32-bit devices and 64-bit drvices. But my app is built for **armeabi** architecture for 32-bit devices and not for **armaebi-v7a**.

So post app build, when all the libraries are merged by build gradle, I cannot see **libcrashlytics.so** library in **armeabi** folder.

```
...build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/.../out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libcrashlytics.so
...build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/.../out/lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics.so
...build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/.../out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libcrashlytics.so
...build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/.../out/lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics.so
```

So when I try to dlopen this library with `dlopen("libcrashlytics.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL));`  my app crashes in 32-bit mobile devices as it is not able to load libcrashlytics library. My app works fine with 64-bit architecture.

But after manually copying **libcrashlytics.so** library to `...build/intermediates/stripped_native_libs/.../out/lib/armaebi/` directory and then building it, solves the problem. In https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis it is mentioned that armaebi-v7a is compatible with armaebi, so it should be fine.

So,

1. Is there any way to provide instruction to gradle to copy "libcrashlytics.so" located in armaebi-v7a to armaebi ?
2. Is there any other way to automate copying during build ?
3. Is there any other work around for my problem ?

Environment -

- Gradle plugin version - 3.5.4
- Gradle version - 5.4.1

**NOTE: Due to few other reasons, I cannot move our app to support "armaebi-v7a"**

Comment: You can refer to "https://github.com/Jween/android-soexcluder/blob/master/app/src/main/groovy/com/jween/gradle/soexcluder/AppPlugin.groovy".